# How can I remove punctuation from a string in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all punctuation from A string but whenever I run my program nothing happens... This is my code:

```
#OPEN file (a christmas carol)
inputFile = open('H:\Documents\Computing\GCSE COMPUTING\Revision\Practice Prog/christmascarol.txt')
carolText = inputFile.read()



#CONVERT everything into lowercase
for line in carolText:
       carolTextlower = carolText.lower()

#REMOVE punctuation (Put a space instead of a hyphened word or apostrophe)
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
noPunctu = carolTextlower.join(ch for ch in carolTextlower if ch not in exclude)
print(noPunctu)
```

When I run my program, nothing appears

Comment: can someone please help

Comment: Give more detail. How are you running the program? What version of Python are you using? what is `inputFile`?

Comment: I tried but someone deleted it all

Comment: You need to structure your code. This is not even readable Alberto!

Comment: ok, you do it better

Comment: Do you want to simply _remove_ all punctuation characters, or do you want to _replace_ each punctuation character with a space character?

Comment: remove all punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
import string

#OPEN file (a christmas carol)
inputFile = open(r'H:\Documents\Computing\GCSE COMPUTING\Revision\Practice Prog/christmascarol.txt')
carolText = inputFile.read()
inputFile.close()

#CONVERT everything into lowercase
carolTextlower = carolText.lower()

#REMOVE punctuation 
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
noPunctu = ''.join(ch for ch in carolTextlower if ch not in exclude)
print(noPunctu)
```

The usual Python convention is to put `import` statements at the top of the script so they're easy to find.

Note that I used a raw string (indicated by the `r` before the opening quote mark) for the file name. It's not strictly necessary here, but it prevents backslash sequences in Windows paths from being interpreted as escape sequences. Eg in `'H:\Documents\new\test.py'` the `\n` would be interpreted as a newline character and the `\t` would be interpreted as a tab character.

You really should close a file after you've finished reading (or writing) it. However, it's better to use the `with` keyword to open files: that ensures the file gets closed properly even if there's an error. Eg,

```
filename = r'H:\Documents\Computing\GCSE COMPUTING\Revision\Practice Prog/christmascarol.txt'
with open(filename) as inputFile:
    carolText = inputFile.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following code:

```
import string

inputFile = open('H:\Documents\Computing\GCSE COMPUTING\Revision\Practice Prog/christmascarol.txt')
carolText = inputFile.read()

for c in string.punctuation:
    carolText=carolText.replace(c,"")

carolText
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can open a file, replace a certain character in it, and write everything in a new file again.

```
to_replace = '-'  # Hyphen
replace_by = ' '  # Space

# Reading the file to be modified.
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Modifying the contents as the file is being read.
    new_file = [line.replace(to_replace, replace_by) for line in file]

# Writing the contents, both modified and untouched ones, in a new file. 
with open('file_modified.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in new_file:
        print(item, file=file, end='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using Python's `translate` function. The code makes a table to map any uppercase character into its matching lowercase character and also converts any punctuation character into a space. This is done in a single call for the whole of the text, so it is very fast:

```
import string

def process_text(s):
    return s.translate(
        str.maketrans(
            string.punctuation + string.ascii_uppercase, 
            " " * len(string.punctuation) + string.ascii_lowercase)).replace("  ", " ")

with open(r'H:\Documents\Computing\GCSE COMPUTING\Revision\Practice Prog/christmascarol.txt') as inputFile:
    print(process_text(inputFile.read()))
```